# create new database from two dataframes, with different rows

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I have two dataframes, `df1` of 19600 rows and `df2` of 18830 rows, `df2$id` finds correspondence in the `df1$id`, while the remaining 770 have no correspondence, I would like to merge the two dataframes creating `df3` with column `df3$id` equal to `df1$id` , if the row matches `df2` it gives me values ​​`df2$value`, otherwise it gives me 0, so in the 770 unmatched places I will have 0 as value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to recreate your problem with a toy data set:

```r
df1 <- data.frame(id = 1:5, values = 1:5)
df2 <- data.frame(id = 3:7, values = 6:10)

df1
#>   id values
#> 1  1      1
#> 2  2      2
#> 3  3      3
#> 4  4      4
#> 5  5      5

df2
#>   id values
#> 1  3      6
#> 2  4      7
#> 3  5      8
#> 4  6      9
#> 5  7     10
```

Then the naive way to achieve this in base R would be:

```r
df3        <- df1
df3$values <- df2$values[match(df3$id, df2$id)]
df3$values[is.na(df3$values)] <- 0
```

Resulting in:

```r
df3
#>   id values
#> 1  1      0
#> 2  2      0
#> 3  3      6
#> 4  4      7
#> 5  5      8
```

You will see that `id` 1 and 2 appear in `df1` but not `df2`. The final result has 0 for the `values` column in these rows, but where there is a match, the correct `values` from `df2` are written in the corresponding position.

<sup>Created on 2022-02-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Using `data.table()`:

```
library(data.table)

DT1 =  data.table(ID = c(1:15),
                  Value = c(3:10))

DT2 = data.table(ID = c(1:10),
                 Value = c(7:13))
```

Join the tables and then recode the variable:

```
DT3 = DT2[DT1, on = .(ID)][, .(ID,Value)]

DT3[!ID %in% DT2$ID, Value := 0] 

tail(DT3)
```

Output

```
 ID Value
1: 10     9
2: 11     0
3: 12     0
4: 13     0
5: 14     0
6: 15     0
```